# What was Sherlock's backup plan in "The Lying Detective"?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In Sherlock season 4, episode 2: "The Lying Detective", had John not shown up at the exact moment Sherlock was being smothered by Smith, wouldn't he have died? Did he have a backup plan (other than switching the drip bag to saline, which clearly wasn't sufficient)?

Comment: Not sure if Sherlock is the kind of person to have a back-up plan...

Comment: Towards the end of this episode, Sherlock mentions he had several other back up plans but doesn't remember them now... Just another glitch in the countless number of glitches season 4 has offered to its viewers :(

Answer (score 1):

It's Sherlock. He doesn't need a backup plan. If he wasn't 100% certain that John would show up at exactly the right moment he would never have gone through with the plan. That's my opinion at least.